# Visualforce Sites HTTPS

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, sites

What is the best way to make a sites page HTTPS only?

A pretty simple question but I haven't found been able to find a good solution.

Thanks.

Comment: usually it is configured in the server that runs the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [Site Level Security](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm) on the Site definition record (Your Name | Setup | Develop | Sites). If this value is not set on the Site, it defaults to the value in the Security Controls (Your Name | Setup | Security Controls | Session Settings). Check the linked document for more information.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, just to clarify in a public site when a user makes a payment - we have to log that user in, to secure the payment page via https?

Comment: That's how I forced https previously, but I'm unable to test now. So, I'm not entirely sure.